# How to check if in list in dictionary is a key?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
a = {'values': [{'silver': '10'}, {'gold': '50'}]}
```

Now I would like to check if the key 'silver' is in the dictionary:

```
if 'silver' in a['values']:
```

But I receive the error:

```
NameError: name 'silver' is not defined
```

So how can I achieve that in python?

Comment: Are you sure you got that error from that exact code? Please share the entire error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if key exists in list of dicts in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790980/how-can-i-check-if-key-exists-in-list-of-dicts-in-python)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any).

```
if any('silver' in d for d in a['values']):
   # do stuff
```

Answer (score 4):

```py
# Notice that a['values'] is a list of dictionaries.
>>> a = {'values': [{'silver': '10'}, {'gold': '50'}]}

# Therefore, it makes sense that 'silver' is not inside a['values'].
>>> 'silver' in a['values']
False

# What is inside is {'silver': '10'}.
>>> a['values']
[{'silver': '10'}, {'gold': '50'}]
```

---

```py
# To find the matching key, you could use the filter function.
>>> matches = filter(lambda x: 'silver' in x.keys(), a['values'])

# 'next' allows you to view the matches the filter found. 
>>> next(matches)
{'silver': '10'}

# 'any' allows you to check if there is any matches given the filter. 
>>> any(matches):
True
```

- [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)
- [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next)
- [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
if 'silver' in a['values'][0].keys():
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take a list interpolation approach, you can flatten the list of dicts into a list of keys like so:

```
In: [key for pair in a['values'] for key in pair.keys()]
Out: ['silver', 'gold']
```

Then:

```
In: 'silver' in [key for pair in a['values'] for key in pair.keys()]
Out: True
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/3538313) to flattening a list of lists.